# Python selenium script can't conenct to browser

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have this script that was able to connect to a browser that is run by this command:
`"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222`. For some reason, it stopped working.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options

edge_options = Options()
edge_options.add_experimental_option('debuggerAddress', '127.0.0.1:9222')

driver = webdriver.Edge(options=edge_options)
driver.get(youtube.com)
print(driver.title)
```

Part of the error message is this:

```
Message: unknown error: cannot connect to microsoft edge at 127.0.0.1:9222
from chrome not reachable
```

Two questions about this message:
Could I just connect to the IP address of the "real" browser?
Why is there written chrome instead of  chromium?

This is a **full error message** it makes me swallow.

[image]

Comment: Can you try to run Edge with a new profile?

Comment: Not precisely, I've managed to connect on it. Then I tried to connect to the new user with success. So then I've been attempting the "basic" user with cusses only on the first try. Then It has the same big error.

Comment: @MahsumAkbas Akbas I've managed to do it. YES, it DOES work with the new profile and port! If the user directory is different than the basic one it does connect. Do you have any tips, please?